# can spring do this guice-like override of bindings?

Tags: spring

In Guice, I have a ProductionModule with my bindings.  In my tests, I can load that PLUS a module that overrides a few of the production bindings with mock objects.  How do I do such a thing in spring....

For example, load production-spring.xml in test files and then have the test load in test-spring.xml which would ONLY override some of the bindings in production-spring.xml

This tests the integration and make sure changes in production-spring.xml don't break things.  These are more automated integration tests then testing a unit and work extremely well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override beans by listing multiple xml files. Beans in the later files will override those loaded before.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
      locations = {"classpath:prodDB.xml", 
                   "classpath:applicationContext.xml", 
                   "classpath:testDb.xml"})
public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    protected DataSource dataSource; //uses the datasource from testDb.xml

}
```

So in this case testDB.xml overrides the DataSource configured in prodDb.xml. This applies even if you don't use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as well:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]
        {"classpath:prodDb.xml",
         "classpath:testDb.xml"});
```

Using a tool like [Constretto](https://constretto.jira.com/wiki/display/CC/Constretto) you can do the same with annotated beans:

```
@Service
public class FooService...

@Service
@Environment("test")
public class FakeFooService ...
```

Now, if you run a test with the `@Environment("test")` annotation on the class, the FakeFooService will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In test environment, you can add your Spring context xml with with overwritten beans before other declarations. And there is also external properties you can change for each environment.